# how would you write taylor series for higher order dimension in this case?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_d)$ and let $g(λ)=f_i(x+λ(y-x))$ for $λ\in\mathbb R$ and $1\le i\le d$. How can I write a Taylor expansion for $g(λ)$ giving the remainder term at 2nd order? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use may use $$
{d\over dt} f(u+tv)=\nabla f(u+tv)^T\cdot v
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are vectors and the equality actually comes from a simple partial differentiation by hand.